# Downloading Files in Flutter_Webview

Tags: flutter, dart, download, flutterwebviewplugin

I am Using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) Package for displaying Web Page.In the Webpage we had a feature to download file. logic for the Downloading File is Similar to below code

```
        filename = "my-file.txt"
        content = 'any string generated by django'
        response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
        print(response)
        return response
```

It is working fine when it is called directly in the browser but had no effect when it comes to Flutter Webview. Is there anything to be done manually to process it. Even I am open to change the Package. I tried [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) also since it had a feature like Download listener but it is not getting triggered when download button pressed.

Thanks in advance